# K3s - dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: k3s

I created a K3s multi-master embedded cluster like this:

hostname: k3s01

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=xxx INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable servicelb --disable traefik --bind-address=10.0.0.4 --tls-san 10.0.0.4 --node-external-ip=168.119.x.x --node-ip=10.0.0.4 --flannel-iface=enp7s0 --advertise-address=PUBIP-OF-LB --cluster-init" sh -
```

hostname: k8s02

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=xxx INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable servicelb --disable traefik --bind-address=10.0.0.2 --tls-san 10.0.0.2 --node-ip 10.0.0.2 --node-external-ip=168.119.x.x  --flannel-iface=enp7s0 --server=https://10.0.0.4:6443" sh -
```

hostname: k8s03

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=xxx INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable servicelb --disable traefik --bind-address=10.0.0.3 --tls-san 10.0.0.3 --node-ip 10.0.0.3 --node-external-ip=168.119.x.x  --flannel-iface=enp7s0 --server=https://10.0.0.4:6443" sh -
```

I can connect from my local machine with kubectl via the LB-IP!
LB: tcp 6443 -> 6443

I can also use kubectl from within any of the nodes above.
I deployed CSI for Hetzner, that also works fine. Tested with their test-deployment!

However, after all of that (working fine so far) i tried to install ingress-nginx.
The deployment started without any issue.
But i found there is an issue communicating with the apiserver from within the cluster, as the following log of the ingress-nginx-controller shows:

```
E1204 11:42:25.216392       8 leaderelection.go:321] error retrieving resource lock ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/configmaps/ingress-controller-leader-nginx": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

Hm, Strange! Ok, let's do some checks:

```
kubectl get svc kubernetes -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-04T11:22:25Z"
  labels:
    component: apiserver
    provider: kubernetes
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:component: {}
          f:provider: {}
      f:spec:
        f:clusterIP: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: k3s
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-04T11:22:25Z"
  name: kubernetes
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "10434"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes
  uid: f0993556-3b7f-40aa-a293-45170cb03002
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.0.1
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Looks gtm.

```
kubectl get endpoints -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Endpoints
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2020-12-04T11:22:25Z"
    labels:
      endpointslice.kubernetes.io/skip-mirror: "true"
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:endpointslice.kubernetes.io/skip-mirror: {}
        f:subsets: {}
      manager: k3s
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-12-04T11:23:39Z"
    name: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "808"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/kubernetes
    uid: cb450392-b4c9-4c2f-bfde-1a3b20ac4b5d
  subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 167.233.x.x
    - ip: 168.119.x.x
    - ip: 168.119.x.x
    ports:
    - name: https
      port: 6443
      protocol: TCP
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Ok, why are Pub IPs here?
lets check it from within one pod to call one of the IP directly:

```
kubectl exec -it ingress-controler-pod-xxxx -- bash

bash-5.0$ curl https://167.233.x.x:6443 --insecure
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}bash-5.0$ curl https://10.43.0.1:443
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.43.0.1 port 443: Connection refused
```

Ok.. thats strange!

Also sometimes some errors like:

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp: lookup k8s02: Try again
```

appear when i try top exex into a pod or display logs.
That only happens when i try to do this to a destination pod running on another host.

Is there something wrong with DNS?

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I cant resolve my hosts by their name. However i have just specified IPs in the K3s Setup.
Do i need working DNS between my Hosts?
Is there something wrong with my K3s Install Params?

Comment: Seems Like Master and Node can't be colocated on the same host

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, caused by a misconfigured DNS resolution, check if you can resolve the nodes hostnames to each other.